# Preposition for "the night before something"

Tags: prepositions, time

Say our flight is on July 10. On July 9 at night, Stacy found her passport was expired.

Is the following sentence idiomatic?

**At the last night before our flight, Stacy found her passport was expired.**

Are "at" and "before" correct here?

Answer (score 2):

We would say:

> **On** the night before our flight...

There is no need to say "last night"... that would imply it was the last night in a sequence of nights. The expression "last minute" has become idiomatic to mean the absolute final moments *before* something, but when it's not an idiom we take words at face value.

The other word I would change is:

> ... Stacy found her passport **had** expired.

Some would argue "was expired" is fine. 'Expired' is the past participle of the verb *to expire*, which is why I would say it "had" expired, but the word can also be used to refer to a *status* of something, like saying "this is *out of date*".

Comment: Nice answers to the unasked questions as well, esp. the nuance with **expired**.

Comment: Then what if on July 8, she found passport had expired. Do you say "On the second to the last night before our flight ..."?